# Do I need a multiple entry visa to go from Abu Dhabi to Jeddah for my Manila flight?

Tags: visas, transit, filipino-citizens, uae, saudi-arabia

I am Filipino. I work in Saudi Arabia and I have a single exit re-entry visa. I'll be going to Abu Dhabi (UAE) from Jeddah, for a week. I'll be coming back to Jeddah for my flight to the Philippines. I have 2 hours and 50 minutes between my time of arrival at 9 pm and the 11:50 pm flight to Manila, Philippines. Do I need to get a multiple visa?

Comment: Did you book a single itinerary from AUH-MNL or separate tickets?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a visa if you meet these requirements:

> Passengers transiting through Dammam (DMM), Jeddah (JED) or Riyadh
>   (RUH) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country
>   within 12 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of
>   the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

Source: Timatic